# Equations of all planes containing a given line, and at a particular distance from origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have the line $G=\{x=(1,2,3)^T+t(1,0,1)^T∈R^3:t∈R\}$

The problem is to determine all planes $∈ R^3$ in the normal form containing $G$ and having distance $\sqrt{2}$ from the origin.

What I have learnt so far is: the normal form of a plane in $R^3$ is given by $a.x=\rho$ and the distance of any point $y$ from this plane can be calculated by $d=\frac {|a.y-\rho|}{∥a∥}$.

In general, $a$ is a normal vector to the plane. However, if it is normed, then the constant $\rho$ on the R.H.S. gives the distance of the plane from the origin.

However, I am unable to figure out how to tackle this problem. How can equations be formed using the fact that the plane contains the given line and is at a distance $\sqrt{2}$ from the origin? Please help.

Comment: If you visualise the problem, you can see that there two solutions (the shortest distance to the line is $\sqrt{6}$), and that the point on the $\sqrt{2}$ disc that touches the plane must be perpendicular to the line.

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed there are! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to solve the problem. I'll put this up in case someone needs it:

The normal form of the required plane can be written as $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3=ρ$ where $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)^T$ is the unit normal vector to the plane and $ρ$ is the perpendicular distance of the plane from the origin.

$a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$ can then be found from the system of equations:

$a.(1,0,1)^T=0$ (since $a$ is normal to the plane)

$a.(1,2,3)^T=\sqrt{2}$ (since the point $(1,2,3)^T$ lies on the plane and satifies its equation)

$\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}=1$ (since $a$ it is a unit vector)

By solving for $a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$, the equations of the two planes satisfying the given conditions can be obtained.